# docker build apk add fails on fetch with kubernetes gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab

i've got a kubernetes cluster on my root server and there vm's.
There is a gitlab running with usage of kubernetes pipelines.
Now the problem, in my Dockerfile I have the following lines:

```
# Install packages we want to keep
RUN apk --no-cache add git zlib-dev curl libzip-dev
# Install dependencies that are only used during installation of other     packages. Afterwards it will be cleaned up.
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    $PHPIZE_DEPS \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j"$(/usr/bin/nproc)" mbstring opcache zip \
&& pecl install xdebug-$XDEBUG_VERSION \
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug zip \
&& apk del .build-deps
```

The first apk add is okay and is executed correctly. On the second apk add 
the pipeline fails with a timeout and the following last lines

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 15m0s seconds
```

Does any one knows thisor have the same error and a solution?
Thanks

Comment: What's the content of $PHPIZE_DEPS?